# Wrap text around relative positioned div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a square div that is housing a javascript image slideshow. I incorporated a caption into the slideshow which requires the containing div to be position:relative. I then want text to wrap around this slideshow... is this possible?

My pseudo structure:

```
<div position:relative>
  <div slideshow stuff>
    <div position:absolute>Caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I wrap text around this?

Answer (score 2):

Damn, it's always AFTER I post for help that I figure it out. Doh.

For those interested, this is my solution (again in pseudo code):

```
<div position:relative float:left margin-left/bottom:20px>
  <div slideshow stuff>
    <div position:absolute>Caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>this text now wraps</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the div if you want to wrap text around it.